# creating navigation bar with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a navigation bar following is my code:
html:
 This is Navigation baar

```
<div class="cat-set">
  <div class="icon-wrap">
    <div class="icons active" id="mobiles"><div class="bgimg mobiles"></div></div>
    <div class="icons" id="laptops"><div class="bgimg laptops"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

on hover of each `'.icons'` class a division will be shown, so there are two boxes to show and hide, this is the code for this:

```
<div class="cat-demo" id="mobiles">
  <p>This is for mobiles, if mouse is on .mobiles then this will be shown</p>
</div>
<div class="cat-demo" id="tablets">
  <p>This is for tablets, if mouse is on .mobiles then this will be shown</p>
</div>
```

this is Jquery code for this:

```
$('.icons').hover(function(){
  $('.icons').each(function(){$(this).removeClass("active");});
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var position = $(this).position();
  $('.cat-demo').css({'left':(position.left-4)+'px'});
  var showThis=$(this).attr("id")
  $(".cat-demo:visible").hide()
  $("'#"+showThis+".cat-demo'").show();
});
```

So till here everything is working fine, but problem is I want to hide the `'.cat-demo'`
if mouse pointer is out of out of `'.icons'` and if pointer is on `.cat-demo` then it should not hide this. please help me... If you want to change the html layout please go ahead.

this is the fiddle link for this http://jsfiddle.net/ndevJ/

Comment: Can you make http://jsfiddle.net/ demo for this

Comment: I don't fully understand your last paragraph. You want to have a navigation bar with 3 elements and, if you go through it(mouse in) or any of the elements inside, it shows the bar or hides, if go out (mouse out)?

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/ndevJ/

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ndevJ/ i want to hide the cat demo on mouseout event.

Comment: @BharatSoni is this what did you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ndevJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is it so necessary to use js for such types of menus? 
If your menu has simple behavior, then use only CSS for show/hide menu's sub items.

For example:

```
<ul class="cat-set">
    <li>
        mobile
        <p>
            This is for mobiles, if mouse is on .mobiles then this will be shown
        </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        laptops
        <p>
            his is for tablets, if mouse is on .mobiles then this will be shown
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
ul.cat-set > li {display: inline-block; margin: 10px;}
ul.cat-set > li p {display: none; position: absolute;}
ul.cat-set > li:hover p {display: block;}
```